# How to call stored procedure and display what it returns in mvc 4 without using EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, stored-procedures

I'm new to mvc and I'm trying to figure out how to connect to a database, call a stored procedure and display what it returns without using entity framework. I created a textbox and it suppose to filter the display based on user input (i.e. id number). There are a lot of columns in the db that needed to be displayed so if possible I prefer not creating a variable for each column in my Model. I've seen an example where they used model as strongly typed System.Data.DataTable, which works, but I ran into an issue since view doesn't allow two models and there for I couldn't use my textbox.

Does anyone know how can this be done, and would be able to shed some light into this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hi my suggestion is you can use Ado.net entity data model for executing the stored procedures . Here is the complete example of how to do this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vendettamit/calling-an-stored-procedure-using-ado-net-entity-model/

And for the problem **view doesn't allow two models** , we can use the concept of viewmodel and combine as many as model we want.

ex:

```
Public class sampleviewmodel
{
     public DataTable propertyname1{get;set;}
     public yourtype  propertyname2{get;set;}

}
```

MoreInfo: http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/understanding-viewmodel-in-aspnet-mvc

Hope the above information was helpful.

Thanks

Karthik

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can call a stored procedure directly without first importing the stored procedure in Entity Framework.  Put a break point after the call to see what is being returned.  Of course change the stored procedure name in `commandText`. You may open DB connection other ways too. You may already be using DB in your project so you would know this.

```
 using (YourDBContext db = new YourDBContext()) {

    Common.DbConnection conn = db.Database.Connection;
    ConnectionState initialState = conn.State;

    if (initialState != ConnectionState.Open) {
        conn.Open();
    }


    using (Common.DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
        cmd.CommandText = "show master status";
        dynamic dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int index = 0;
        List<string> columns = new List<string>();
        for (index = 0; index <= dr.FieldCount - 1; index++) {
            string columnName = dr.GetName(index);
        }
        if (dr.HasRows) {
            while (dr.Read()) {
                //'
                //'
            }
        }
        dr.Close();
      }
    }
```

Comment: I was able to connect to the db and call the stored proc, but it's not letting me display it. I created a form with textbox user enters their id on the textbox, then it's suppose to pass it as parameter in the stored proc, but it's not displaying any table after that.

Comment: Well put a breakpoint and see what is being returned from DB.